# How to obtain structured results with YOLOv8 similar to YOLOv5's results.pandas().xyxy method?

Tags: python, pandas, yolov8

I am currently working with YOLOv8 and I'm wondering if there is a method similar to `results.pandas().xyxy` available in YOLOv5 to obtain structured results in tabular form.
With YOLOv5, it's possible to get results easily using the following code:

```py
results = model(img)
df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # Get results in tabular format
print(df)
#      xmin    ymin    xmax   ymax  confidence  class    name
# 0  749.50   43.50  1148.0  704.5    0.874023      0  person
# 1  433.50  433.50   517.5  714.5    0.687988     27     tie
# 2  114.75  195.75  1095.0  708.0    0.624512      0  person
# 3  986.00  304.00  1028.0  420.0    0.286865     27     tie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such method for the YOLOv8 `Results` object. But after some manipulations with the data it contains, you can get the necessary information in the required format.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_pandas(results):
  # translate boxes data from a Tensor to the List of boxes info lists
  boxes_list = results[0].boxes.data.tolist()
  columns = ['x_min', 'y_min', 'x_max', 'y_max', 'confidence', 'class_id']

  # iterate through the list of boxes info and make some formatting
  for i in boxes_list:
    # round float xyxy coordinates:
    i[:4] = [round(i, 1) for i in i[:4]]
    # translate float class_id to an integer
    i[5] = int(i[5])
    # add a class name as a last element
    i.append(result[0].names[i[5]])

  # create the result dataframe
  columns.append('class_name')
  result_df = pd.DataFrame(boxes_list, columns=columns)

  return result_df
```

The usage example:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8m.pt')
results = model(image)
get_pandas(results)
```

Output:

```
image 1/1 /content/drive/MyDrive/IMG.jpg: 480x640 1 cat, 1 laptop, 29.3ms
Speed: 3.2ms preprocess, 29.3ms inference, 1.2ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640)
#   x_min   y_min   x_max   y_max   confidence  class_id    class_name
#0  567.9   142.0   2666.5  2728.0  0.625634    15          cat
#1  1282.4  1.3     2667.4  607.8   0.407192    63          laptop
```